# How to update views currently instantiated by ViewPager

Tags: android

I know the view pager must instantiate at least three layouts at the same time. I can update the layout on-screen, but how do I update the other two layouts?

For example, say I have a green ViewPager layout that fills the entire screen.

Every-time the user clicks on the screen, I want the background color to change from green to purple.

I can change the color of the layout on screen, but how do I change the color of remaining two layouts that have been instantiated (without re-instantiating them)?

The idea would be that the user could page to left or right, and screen would already be green.

Here is my `pager_layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0"
    android:id="@+id/pager_layout">

</LinearLayout>
```

Here I set up a `CustomAdapter` class and a cick listener

```
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup pager_layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_layout, collection, false);
        collection.addView(pager_layout);

        setListener(pager_layout);

        return pager_layout;
    }

    //etc...
}
```

Here is my `setListener();` method

```
public void setListener(final View pager_layout){

    pager_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            l.setBackgroundColor(17170458); // purple
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally

```
pager_layout.setTag(position);
...
View layout = collection.findViewWithTag(position+1); 
layout.setBackgroundColor(17170458);
```

I could also do something more complicated like modifying views within the layout itself

```
View layout = collection.findViewWithTag(position+1);
layout.findViewById(R.id.view1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
layout.findViewById(R.id.view2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the page position you can use the following solution. Let's say you want to modify the page at position `position` in your view pager.

I advice you to extend from [`FragmentPagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) rather than `PagerAdapter` as you can then embed anything you need inside a custom fragment `ColorFragment`. That fragment can define a method `setBackgroundColor()`. Then you use the following call in your main activity:

```
ColorFragment colorFragment = (ColorFragment) customAdapter.getItem(position)
colorFragment.setBackgroundColor(17170458);
```

If you want to modify the color of the currently visible fragment, you can set position to `viewPager.getCurrentItem()`.